# Webapp with Python back-end. Should I use AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to build a webapp with Python back-end. The front-end of the webapp will just have a simple input box where the user puts an address. Then, on the back-end I want to scrape content from the webpage in that address and then process that data. This data processing might become quite heavy.

I'm quite experienced with Python, although with webapps, hosting, and so on, I have zero experience. I bought a domain name and hosting on namecheap, even though I just found out that maybe I won't be needing to use their hosting, as someone in /r/webhosting recommended me to use AWS instead. This was the methodology I was recommended to follow:

> - switch to AWS (or Azure)
> - create python lambda/function to do whatever you want to do with this request...
> - put lambda behind api-gateway
> - put Cloudfront in front of api-gateway (optional but hey..)

I have seen tutorials to point the namecheap domain into an EC2 instance. But how do I go about doing this with Lambda? Is it the same principle? Can you point me to any tutorials that might teach me how to handle this? Is Lambda actually the optimal solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great starting point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html

Aws sam handles creation and deployment of your Lambda and API Gateway. To have your API/web app exposed to a custom domain, you will need to create a AWS ACM SSL certificate and create a custom domain on your API Gateway. Basically it will create a hidden Cloudfront Distribution that you can use to setup your DNS.

Good luck!